# int schema.org what's the different Actors vs Actor

Tags: schema.org

In http://schema.org/Movie 
i find the words :
 Actors and Actor.
but i can't understand，what's the what's the different between  Actors vs Actor ?

**actor Person  A cast member of the movie, TV series, season, or episode, or video.
actors  Person  A cast member of the movie, TV series, season, or episode, or video. (legacy spelling; see singular form, actor)**

any one can understand that?

Comment: The phrase *legacy spelling* is the key.  In an earlier version of the schema, they spelled the property *actors*.  Then, they decided that *actor* was better, but they could not remove the old property because it was in use.

Answer (score 3):

Because every property in Schema.org can be repeated and it is better to break out each individual actor, property names went through singularization. This was meant to clear up some confusion about what the plural form meant. The plural forms are kept around for backwards compatibility, but are deprecated. You can read more about all of the changes to singular here:
http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/Singularity

Don't use the legacy plural forms.